# ML.Net Averaged Perceptron only ever returns false

Tags: c#, ml.net, perceptron

I’m having a bit of trouble getting my Averaged Perceptron binary classifier to work in ML.Net.
I have a simple set of data where if stat1 is greater than or equal to 50 then the result is true, if not false. This training file has around 320 entries.

Example

| Stat1 | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 60 | TRUE |
| 84 | TRUE |
| 69 | TRUE |
| 95 | TRUE |
| 48 | FALSE |
| 88 | TRUE |
| 35 | FALSE |

I’m loading this into my dataview and setting up the label and features columns. The metrics that are retuned indicate that it is accurate (probably too accurate at 100% success rate) but when I test it, it only ever returns false no matter what I put as the input.

Here is my code

```
static class SimpleTest
{
    public static void RunSimpleTest()
    {
        MLContext mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 0);

        List<TextLoader.Column> mlCols = new List<TextLoader.Column>();

        mlCols.Add(new TextLoader.Column("Stat1", DataKind.Single, 0));
        mlCols.Add(new TextLoader.Column("Result", DataKind.Boolean, 1));

        IDataView dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile("BC_AP CSV Data Simple.csv", mlCols.ToArray(), ',', true, true, true, false);

        var split = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(dataView);

        IDataView trainingDataView = split.TrainSet;
        IDataView testingDataView = split.TestSet;

        IEstimator<ITransformer> pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.CopyColumns("Label", "Result");

        List<string> concatCols = new List<string>()
        {
            "Stat1"
        };

        pipeline = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", concatCols.ToArray()));
        pipeline = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMeanVariance("Features", "Features"));

        var trainer = mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.AveragedPerceptron();

        var trainingPipeline = pipeline.Append(trainer);
        var trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainingDataView);

        IDataView predictions = trainedModel.Transform(testingDataView);
        var metrics = mlContext.BinaryClassification.EvaluateNonCalibrated(predictions);

        Console.WriteLine($"*Metrics for {trainer.ToString()} classifier model");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine($"Accuracy: {metrics.Accuracy:F2}");
        Console.WriteLine($"AUC: {metrics.AreaUnderRocCurve:F2}");
        Console.WriteLine($"F1 Score: {metrics.F1Score:F2}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Negative Precision: " + $"{metrics.NegativePrecision:F2}");

        Console.WriteLine($"Negative Recall: {metrics.NegativeRecall:F2}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Positive Precision: " + $"{metrics.PositivePrecision:F2}");

        Console.WriteLine($"Positive Recall: {metrics.PositiveRecall:F2}\n");
        Console.WriteLine(metrics.ConfusionMatrix.GetFormattedConfusionTable());
        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);

        var predEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<SimpleDataObj, SimplePredDataObj>(trainedModel);

        SimpleDataObj dataObj = new SimpleDataObj(99);

        Console.WriteLine("Data for prediction - Expecting True");
        Console.WriteLine(dataObj.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);

        var predData = predEngine.Predict(dataObj);

        Console.WriteLine("Result");
        Console.WriteLine(predData.Result);
    }

    public class SimpleDataObj
    {
        [LoadColumn(0)]
        public float Stat1 = 0;
        [LoadColumn(1)]
        public bool Result;

        public SimpleDataObj()
        {
        }

        public SimpleDataObj(float stat1)
        {
            Stat1 = stat1;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.AppendLine("Stat1 = " + Stat1);

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class SimplePredDataObj
    {
        [ColumnName("Result")]
        public bool Result { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have also created a sample application that will demonstrate the issue in github

https://github.com/XactaAndy/AvgPerceptTest

Any ideas on why it is going wrong?